# Cannot make static reference to the non-static method (Java)

Tags: java, methods, reference, static

```
g.drawString(p2.getName(), 800 - FontMetrics.stringWidth(p2.getName()), 40);
```

That line results in the error " Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method stringWidth(String) from the type FontMetrics.

The `getName()` method is defined in the player class, and p2 is an instance of that class, so I don't see how `p2.getName()` is a static reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an instance of `FontMetrics`. You can obtain one from the `Graphics` object:

```
g.drawString(p2.getName(), 800 - g.getfontMetrics().stringWidth(p2.getName()), 40);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it is not - the static reference is `stringWidth`.

`FontMetrics.stringWidth` is an instance method. The error message is:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method **stringWidth(String)** from the type **FontMetrics**

Comment: So how would you fix this?

Comment: @OliverBennett that depends - you need to obtain a FontMetrics instance and call it as `fontMetrics.stringWidth(p2.getName())`, `fontMetrics` is the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

The `stringWidth()` method is not a static method and needs an instance of `FontMetrics` to access it.

You are accessing it as a static method, so it gives you the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
g.getFontMetrics.stringWidth("your string")
```

Comment: You need `getFontMetrics()` instead of `getFontMetrics`.